# Options for displaying metrics stored in Cassandra to Grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, graphite, grafana

I installed graphite web, graphite-cyanite and configured cyanite. Then created the metric keyspace and table in my cassandra cluster as suggested in cyanite documentation and I am able to successfully insert data into metric table. Then I went ahead and installed grafana and elastic search and configured them by adding the below index to cyanite.yaml.

index:
  use: "io.cyanite.es_path/es-rest"
  index: "my_paths" #defaults to "cyanite_paths"
  url: "http://myhost:9200" 
  chan_size: 1000 # defaults to 1000
  batch_size: 1000 # defaults to 1000

Now I am lost with my options on how to proceed to retrieve the metric data from my cassandra cluster/elasticsearch to display the graphs on Grafana. Please advise.

Comment: What did you finally end up doing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Grafana integrates with Graphite via the graphite web api.

Sinces you mentioned that you installed graphite-web. Configure a grafana graphite data source and specify the url of your graphite-web instance:
http://docs.grafana.org/installation/#graphite-elasticsearch-setup-example